# DiscordjsError: Request to use token, but token was unavailable to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Hi I'm creating a bot for my server and I was trying to make a member counter in voice channels and when I finished doing it I wrote in the terminal: `node index.js` and he started saying that the token was not available to my client.

ERROR:

```
(node:9596) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordjsError: Request
to use token, but token was unavailable to the client. at RequestHandler.execute
```

Here is [my code](https://hastebin.com/yavatahusi.typescript)

Note: I did all the bot code in a file just to be able to use it in a .bat file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because on line 6 where you try to fetch, you're not logged in. You're calling `bot.login()` later (and it's async)

```
const guild = bot.guilds.fetch('222078108977594368')
```

Check https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/errors.html#request-to-use-token-but-token-was-unavailable-to-the-client

If you want to fetch it only once, you can probably move this to the `ready` state's handler:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const { send, stdout } = require('process')

const bot = new Discord.Client()
const token = 'XXX'
const prefix = 'a!'
// use let, so you can change it later in bot.on('ready')
let guild = null

// this event will only trigger after logging in
bot.on('ready', () => {
  const ping = new Date()
  // fetch here
  guild = bot.guilds.fetch('222078108977594368')

  ping.setHours(ping.getHours() - 3)
  console.log(`BOT INICIADO AS ${ping.getUTCHours()}:${ping.getUTCMinutes()}:${ping.getUTCSeconds()}`)
  console.log('GuruGuru Está Online!')

  bot.user.setActivity(`${bot.guilds.cache.size} servidores`, { type: 'WATCHING' });
})
```

Comment: I'm very dumb! thanks!